# Convert Dataframe to multiple 2D arrays

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have this dataset:

```
+----+-----+-------+-----+
|code|code2|machine|value|
+----+-----+-------+-----+
|   1|    2|      A|   42|
|   2|    1|      A|   11|
|   1|    4|      A|   55|
|   1|    1|      B|    2|
|   3|    3|      B|   34|
|   3|    2|      B|  111|
+----+-----+-------+-----+
```

I want that for each machine a kind of matrix like the following:
code and code2 are the column and at the intersection I want to fill the value.

**Machine A**

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   A|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   0|  11|   0|   0|
|   2|  42|   0|   0|   0|
|   3|   0|   0|   0|   0|
|   4|  55|   0|   0|   0|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

**Machine B**

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   B|   1|   2|   3|   4|
+----+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   0|   0|   0|
|   2|   0|   0| 111|   0|
|   3|   0|   0|  34|   0|
|   4|   0|   0|   0|   0|
+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I have multiple machine there (unknown number) and the codes can only be 0-255. 
So my problem is how to achieve that matrix...

My fist naive idea was to make a hashmap and as key the machine name and as value a 256x256 2D array. But I don't think it would be efficient and I also don't know how to achieve that.

Or probably have a dataset for each machine??

If someone has an idea I would like to listen.

Btw I'm using Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For maximum coding flexibility, you could switch to the RDD API. An example of a solution would give you a RDD that maps a machine to its matrix, represented as a scala two-dimensional array. Note that Array.ofDimInt creates a two-dim array of sine n*m with zeros everywhere.

```
df
    .map(x=> x.getAs[String]("machine") -> (x.getAs[Int]("code"), x.getAs[Int]("code2"),x.getAs[Int]("value")))
    .groupByKey
    .mapValues( seq => {
         var result = Array.ofDim[Int](256, 256)
         seq.foreach{ case (i,j,value) => result(i)(j) = value }
         result
     })
```